# SSH dynamic port forwarding, "Connection refused"

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to do dynamic portforwarding using openssh through a remote computer following this command:

```
ssh -D 6789 rohan@<remote_ip> -p <remote_port>
```

This should set up a socks server on my comp as I assume.

I am able to use this for normal browsing but can't connect to IRC or remote ssh (through proxychains).

I get this error:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

A high verbosity level output of the error:

```
$ debug1: Connection to port 6789 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 3: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 3: pre_dynamic: have 4
debug2: channel 3: decode socks5
debug2: channel 3: socks5 auth done
debug2: channel 3: pre_dynamic: need more
debug2: channel 3: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 3: pre_dynamic: have 10
debug2: channel 3: decode socks5
debug2: channel 3: socks5 post auth
debug2: channel 3: dynamic request: socks5 host 4.2.2.2 port 53 command 1
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 3335
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 3: zombie
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 6789 for 4.2.2.2 port 53, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 33694, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/7 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 3: close_fds r 9 w 9 e -1 c -1
```

I googled for this too, but couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as that: The target computer (in this case `4.2.2.2`) refused the connection.

```
debug2: channel 3: dynamic request: socks5 host 4.2.2.2 port 53 command 1
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 6789 for 4.2.2.2 port 53, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 33694, nchannels 4
```

(I must say that tunnelling DNS over SOCKS this way is *very unusual*, although not related to your problem.)

Are you able to connect from the server to (for example) IRC using interactive commands? (`nc chat.freenode.net 6667`, `irssi -c chat.freenode.net`, and so on). If connections to several different servers fail, it's likely to be a firewall problem on your remote server.

Comment: no i can't connect to freenode irc....

Comment: @dcrodjer: Then it's a problem with your server itself, not related to SSH. Have you checked the firewall(s)? tried different ports? tried SSL connections?

Comment: actually the above same config works with my friends comp...same distro....I guess it should be due to some comps config....Currently the remote comp is off, will share the output of `nmap` on localhost when its back.

Comment: @dcrodjer: If you are unable to connect to Freenode _from the server_ (you haven't told me yet), then it's not caused by SSH. I doubt `nmap` ing the server would help, too -- after all, you are connecting to Freenode, not to `localhost`.

Comment: yeah freenode works on the server...I currently use irssi at the remote account only